# ArrayAdapter is not updating

Tags: java, android, android-arrayadapter

I have recently started working on an android app (I am pretty new to the platform). 
I was just trying to write a simple todo app to learn how array adapters work.

--So once I enter text in the myTextView and press "Enter", I want text to show up in a list view below. As shown in the picture nothing gets updated in the list view.
What am I doing wrong here? please help.

test.java:

```
package com.niranjanbajgai.test;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.KeyEvent;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ListView;


import java.util.ArrayList;


public class test extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_test);

        //Get reference to UI widget.
        final ListView myListView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.myListView);
        final EditText myEditText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.myEditText);

        //Create the array list
        final ArrayList<String> myArrayList = new ArrayList<String>();

        //create an array adapter to bind array to the list view

        final ArrayAdapter<String> myArrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(
                this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, myArrayList);

        myListView.setAdapter(myArrayAdapter);

        myEditText.setOnKeyListener(new View.OnKeyListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onKey(View view, int keyCode, KeyEvent keyEvent) {
                if(keyEvent.getAction() == keyEvent.ACTION_DOWN){
                    if(keyCode == keyEvent.KEYCODE_ENTER){
                        myArrayList.add(0, myEditText.getText().toString());

                        myArrayAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                        myEditText.setText("");
                    }
                    return true;

                }
                return false;
            }
        });

    }


    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.test, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

activity_test.xml:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context=".test">

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/myEditText"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:hint="@string/addItemHint"/>
    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/myListView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

[image]

Comment: put a break point here `myArrayList.add(0, myEditText.getText().toString());` then debug and make sure data is added in the `myArrayList`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want to validate the content of your EditText from the bottom right button of the keyboard right?

Currently, the button allows to add a new line. I think that the onKeyListener is called only when using an hardware keyboard, that's why it's never called.

To change the bottom right button, you need to change the imeOptions of the EditText to actionDone for example.

```
<EditText
    android:id="@+id/myEditText"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:hint="@string/addItemHint"
    android:imeOptions="actionDone" />
```

And then you can remove your onKeyListener by an EditorActionListener :

```
editText.setOnEditorActionListener(new OnEditorActionListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onEditorAction(TextView v, int actionId, KeyEvent event) {
        boolean handled = false;
        if (actionId == EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_DONE) {
            myArrayList.add(0, myEditText.getText().toString());

            myArrayAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            myEditText.setText("");
            handled = true;
        }
        return handled;
    }
});
```

For more details on EditText and the keyboard, you can read the [documentation](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/controls/text.html)

The rest of your code looks good and should work. Simply replace the height of your ListView with match_parent (a ListView should not be wrapped).

Comment: Thanks Julien. If anyone else is having similar issues, I also had to add `android:singleLine="true"` inside `<EditText>` to make make it work.